# Problems with Programmatically Adding UIImageView on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview

I'm trying to programmatically add dots to a radar screen. The code runs without complaint, but I can't seem to get the dots to show up on screen.  I do have a background UIImageView that covers the entire screen, but based on the documentation I expect my new UIImageView to be added to the front (not to mention I've tried bringSubViewToFront:).

Since I'm not sure how to go about debugging this, if someone could show me where I went wrong that would be great.

```
UIImage *dot;
CGRect dotFrame;
UIImageView *dotView;

// loop through enemies, dropping pins
dot = [UIImage imageNamed:@"enemyDot.png"];
dotFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, dot.size.width, dot.size.height);
for(location in enemyAgents){

  // add the dot
  dotView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:dotFrame];
  dotView.center = CGPointMake(100, 100);
  [self.view addSubview:dotView];
  [dotView release];
  dotView = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need to add `dot` to your `dotView`? Something like:

`dotView.image = dot`

Comment: Yep. Thanks for spotting the error.  I've been pouring over this for over an hour and couldn't spot my bonehead mistake.

Comment: No problem. Going outside and taking my mind off the problem usually helps solve things like this. Let's my brain stretch a little.